# Spring Security Oauth2 bearer token custom verification

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring security Oauth2 Jwt token for authentication of rest service. I want to decrypt bearer token and check the user details before Spring Security Oauth verifies it.
Can any one help me how to do?
Thanks

Comment: You should probably add some relevant code you already use into your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.